# Prevent race condition by using resources in tidal scheduler

Tags: algorithm, jobs

I have the following scenario and I need some help on finding a resolution.

I have 4 jobs lined up for execution:

```
A
    1a
    2a
B
    1b
    2b
C
    1c
    2c
D
    1d
    2d
```

Only one job can be running at any given moment and any one can start first. But if job B starts first, I want its child jobs (1b and 2b) to be finished before job A kicks off.

I tried using one shared resource to restrict the number of jobs running at any given time, but this leads to a race condition and I end up with 1a, 2a, 3a, 4a running before 1b,2b.. kick off.

Is there a similar problem out there which I can look at or is there a way to use a combination of more than 1 resources to achieve the desired result?

Comment: By "shared resource" do you mean a mutex lock? Because if you do, "this leads to a race condition" sounds like a bug in your code.

Comment: Not a mutex lock. I am trying to create a job loop in Tidal Scheduler.

Comment: No idea what that is but it might help if you edited that little detail into your post and added tags for it :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a new dummy job in each group with a combination of a resource and a variable depedency to manage mutual exclusive execution.  It would also be easier to manage if you put your child jobs in a new subgroup.

First create a resource, let's call it MutexResource, with a limit of 1.

Next create a variable, let's call it MutexVariable - make it Boolean, default is false

Then you need actions to toggle the variable.  So create these two Variable actions

1. Lock MutexVariable - this is a variable action that sets MutexVariable to true
2. Unlock MutexVariable - this is a variable action that tests the MutexVariable to false

Then create a new job under each group called "Job mutex".  This is just a dummy job to handle the resource and variable which we will set up later, so just make the command "sleep" and the parameter 5 (a sleep for 5 seconds job).

Next create a new group inside each of your existing groups (A-D), let's call it GroupCritical, then move the original child jobs down into that group.

So your new job structure would look like this:

```
Group A
    Job mutex
    GroupCritical
        Job 1a
        Job 2a
Group B
    Job mutex
    GroupCritical
        Job 1b
        Job 2b
Group C
    Job mutex
    GroupCritical
        Job 1c
        Job 2c
Group D
    Job mutex
    GroupCritical
        Job 1d
        Job 2d
```

Now that you have the job structure, modify Job mutex in each group so that it has these

1. A Resource requirement of 1 MutexResource
2. A Variable Dependency on MutexVariable = false
3. Action "Lock MutexVariable" when job status is Active

And on each GroupCritical, add the following

1. Action "Unlock MutexVariable" when job status is Completed

The way this works is as follows.  Only one of the "mutex" jobs will be able to claim the resource prior to launching.  Then when it goes Active (and still holds the resource), it will change the MutexVariable to true.  The other "mutex" jobs will now have their variable dependency go unmet, and they will go back to Waiting on Dependencies and not be able to claim the resource.  The GroupCritical jobs will then run, and when the group as a whole is complete, it will reset the MutexVariable back to false.  At this point, the remaining 3 mutex jobs will have their variable dependency met and will try to obtain the resource.  Only one mutex job will claim the resource, and it will toggle the variable, and the other two "mutex" jobs will go back to Waiting on Dependencies.  And so on.

So the bottom line is each GroupCritical will complete all of its jobs before any other can start.  I tested it in the product and it works well.